# Extract the percent days from a specific month

Tags: sql-server, date, days

I have a table like this one - changes table:

```
Table 1: 
    id  start_date end_date   s_g r_c s_c
    111  1/1/15     25/5/2015  A1  1    0
    111  26/05/2015 31/12/9999 Z1  1    2
    222  1/1/14     10/2/2015  Q1  1    0
    222  11/2/2015  31/12/9999 R1  1    0
```

And I need to build an montly output for 2015 like this:

```
id   month s_g r_c _s_c percent 
111    1    A1  1    0   100%    
111    2    A1  1    0   100%
111    3    A1  1    0   100%
111    4    A1  1    0   100%
111    5    A1  1    0   83.33% 
111    5    Z1  1    2   16.67%
111    6    Z1  1    2   100%
111    7    Z1  1    2   100%
111    8    Z1  1    2   100%
222    1    Q1  1    0   100%    
222    2    Q1  1    0   35.71%     
222    2    R1  1    0   64.29% 
222    3    R1  1    0   100%
222    4    R1  1    0   100%
222    5    R1  1    0   100%
222    6    R1  1    0   100%
222    7    R1  1    0   100% 
222    8    R1  1    0   100%
```

I need this month only for year 2015. 
Any idea how can I build this thing? just assum that those are the only case.

Comment: Can you explain how the output should be generated from the source records?  Can you also show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have a start date and end date and I need to take 4 rows from Table 1 and make an output like I've mentiond. I just need an idea how to prefrom this.

Comment: The first row in your sample data seems to become 5 rows in the expected output.  How does this happen?  What rules govern this transformation?  Why is row one 100% while row five is 83.33%?  The more detail you add to your question, the more likely you are to get a satisfactory answer.  Questions that include an attempt at the answer are also more likely to be answered.  So if you can include the SQL you've tried so far that will help.

Comment: Please explain what you want in **words** rather than post here's the data I have and here's the data I want.

Comment: Not fully explain.Why Z1 will go till 8 only,why not till 12.include start date and endate in your output.Explain calculation of 16.67% and 83.3%

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
    DECLARE @Month_2015 TABLE
    (
        Date1 Date,
        Date2 Date
    )

    INSERT INTO @Month_2015
    select '2015-01-01','2015-01-31'
    union all
    select '2015-02-01','2015-02-28'
    union all
    select '2015-03-01','2015-03-31'
    union all
    select '2015-04-01','2015-04-30'
    union all
    select '2015-05-01','2015-05-31'
    union all
    select '2015-06-01','2015-06-30'
    ...

    With CTE as 
    (
    Select ID, date1, s_g, r_c, s_c, 
            le = case when start_date < Date2 AND End_date > DATE1 THEN Datediff(d,
                                                                           (case when start_date < date1 THEN date1 else start_date end),
                                                                           (case when end_date < date2 THEN end_date else date2 end)
                 Else 0
           end,
           m = DATEDIFF (d, date1, date2)
    from
        Table1, @Month_2015
    )

    Select ID, Month(date1), s_g, r_c, s_c,  (le*100.0 / m) 
    from CTE
    Where le > 0
    order by ID, Month(date1), s_g, r_c, s_c
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this. It worked for me based on your table ##

```
DECLARE @TableRezult TABLE (id INT,month INT,s_g varchar(2),r_c INT,s_c INT,    MonthPercentage varchar(25))

            DECLARE @month INT=1
            WHILE @month<=12
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @TableRezult    
                SELECT id,@month,s_g,r_c,s_c,
                CASE WHEN (end_date >= dateadd(m,1,convert(varchar,@month)+'/1/2015') OR end_date='12/31/2015') 
                AND ([START_DATE]<=convert(varchar,@month)+'/1/2015')  THEN '100%' ELSE 
                    CASE WHEN end_date >= convert(varchar,@month)+'/1/2015' AND end_date < dateadd(m,1,convert(varchar,@month)+'/1/2015') THEN convert(VARCHAR ,Day(end_date)*100.0/DAY(EOMONTH(start_date)))+'%'
                    WHEN start_date >= convert(varchar,@month)+'/1/2015' AND start_date < dateadd(m,1,convert(varchar,@month)+'/1/2015') THEN convert(varchar,(DAY(EOMONTH(start_date))-Day(start_date))*100.0/DAY(EOMONTH(start_date)))+'%'
                    ELSE '0%' END

                     END FROM Table1 WHERE MONTH([START_DATE])<=@month AND MONTH(end_date)>=@month
                SET @month=@month+1
            END
            SELECT * FROM @TableRezult ORDER BY id,[MONTH]
```

Answer (score 0):

since it is not fully explain,i am posting half solution,after clearing doubts calculation can be corrected.

```
declare @Table1 table (id int,start_date datetime,end_date datetime
,  s_g varchar(20), r_c int, s_c int )
insert into @Table1 values
    (111  ,'2015-01-01','2015-5-25','A1',  1,   0 )
    ,(111  ,'2015-05-26','9999-12-31','Z1',  1,   2 )
    ,(222  ,'2014-01-01','2015-02-10','Q1',  1,   0 )
    ,(222  ,'2015-02-11','9999-12-31','R1',  1,   0 )

DECLARE @year INT = 2015

;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,s_g
        ,r_c
        ,s_c
        ,CASE 
            WHEN datepart(year, start_date) = @year
                THEN start_date
            WHEN datepart(year, start_date) < @year
                THEN CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01'
            WHEN datepart(year, start_date) > @year
                THEN CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + '12' + '-' + '31'
            END startdate
        ,CASE 
            WHEN datepart(year, end_date) = @year
                THEN end_date
            WHEN datepart(year, end_date) < @year
                THEN CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01'
            WHEN datepart(year, end_date) > @year
                THEN CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + '12' + '-' + '31'
            END enddate
    FROM @table1
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT A.id
        ,A.s_g
        ,A.r_c
        ,A.s_c
        ,A.startdate
        ,A.enddate
        ,DATEPART(month, A.startdate) MonthList
    FROM CTE A

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.id
        ,A.s_g
        ,A.r_c
        ,A.s_c
        ,dateadd(month, 1, A.startdate)
        ,A.enddate
        ,a.MonthList + 1
    FROM CTE1 A
    WHERE A.MonthList < DATEPART(month, a.enddate)
    )
--select * from cte1
SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN datediff(month, startdate, enddate) >= 1
            THEN 100
        ELSE (datepart(day, enddate) / cast(datepart(day, dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, (datediff(month, 0, enddate) + 1), 0))) AS DECIMAL(4, 2))) * 100
        END
FROM cte1
ORDER BY id
    ,s_g
    ,monthlist
```